# encryption with type information preserved

Tags: encryption

How can we achieve asymmetric key based encryption but with type information preserved, e.g. int to int, string to string, and datetime to datetime etc.

I have a situation where I want this in my application before sending data to any DB. Before sending an object to the document based DB, I want to encrypt the members of the object and set the encrypted value back to the object's members.

The objects are statically typed means let say a c# or java class instance. So the scene is, we cannot assign encrypted value (that is essentially a string) to a non string data type and we don't want to create a copy of the instance holding all the encrypted values in corresponding string members, this way I will lose the type information.

Any help/suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Before sending an object to the document based DB, I want to encrypt the members of the object and set the encrypted value back to the object's members.

So encode the type along with the data. This is completely independent of encryption. Any way that you'd want to encode the data would have this issue; whatever you'd use to encode this to JSON works precisely the same when you encrypt it.

It's important to note that encrypting data is not "essentially a string." The output of encryption is a random series of bytes.

How you implement this in practice is highly dependent on your use case and your language. Different languages have very different kinds of types. But in every language, there is some way to encode data into a serialized format (JSON, Protobuf, etc). That is the thing you want to focus on. Once you are able to convert to and from any serialized format, that format can be encrypted. It's the serialization that matters, not the encryption.

Comment: has a lot inside if anybody wants to grab. thanks for the all the possible information.